# Can I have one @Query for multiple JPA repository methods with different signature and return type?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

For example, we have a JPA repository containing three methods looking for exactly the same DB selection, but presenting it in different forms:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

   ... some repository methods ...

   List<User> findUsersByCustomCriteria(String criteria);

   Set<User> findUsersByCustomCriteria(String criteria, Sort sort);

   Page<User> findUsersByCustomCriteria(String criteria, Pageable pageable);
}
```

and a query

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE ...");
```

Is there an easy way to avoid repeating the same query 3 times, excepts `@NamedQuery` in `User` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I realized that it is possible to declare query as String. But more elegant way suggestions are still welcome, may be I am missing something.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   String QUERY_TEXT = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE ...";

   ... some repository methods ...

   @Query(QUERY_TEXT)
   List<User> findUsersByCustomCriteria(String criteria);

   @Query(QUERY_TEXT)
   Set<User> findUsersByCustomCriteria(String criteria, Sort sort);

   @Query(QUERY_TEXT)
   Page<User> findUsersByCustomCriteria(String criteria, Pageable pageable);
}
```